# How to fix the "raw_depth_java" immediate crash after showing "This device does not support the ARCore Raw Depth API."?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-emulator, augmented-reality

**Hey everyone!**
I am trying to set up the ARCore demo application "raw_depth_java" in Android Studio using an emulator, but it closes immediately every time I open it. For reference:

1. **The emulator I am using:** Android 10.0 Google Play | x86
2. **What I want to happen:** I want to open the demo application and see ARCore.
3. **What is happening:** The emulator sends the message, "This device does not support the ARCore Raw Depth API." The app immediately closes after.
4. **Other relevant information:** I have installed "Google Play Services for AR."

**Question (TLDR): How can I run the "raw_depth_java" application in an emulator?**

Thank you for your help, have a wonderful day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator can't run the ARCore Depth API.

From: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/quickstart#run

> Note: The Depth API is **not supported** when running in the Android Emulator. Use a physical supported device to test the Depth API.